# Good Programming Practice for similar child classes

Tags: object-oriented, mvc, ios

I am developing an iOS application, in which I have to draw some patterns on a view based on option selected by user. Let me explain you more clearly.

User will be shown number of images as options to choose from.

[image]

On selecting an option, a view will be drawn. This view is inheriting from a class say `ParentClass` where I have set up common properties for child classes.

**ParentClass**

```
@interface ParentClass : UIView

-(ImagePlaceHolder *) imageHolderTouched:(CGPoint) position;

//common properties declared

@end
```

Right now, my approach is use of separate classes for each pattern. I override `drawRect:` for different patterns. So that's why I am creating separate child classes for each.

**ChildDesign**

```
@interface ChildDesign : ParentClass

@end

@implementation CollageDesign

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self drawViews];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//different implementation for different classes
}

@end
```

There are many similar child classes just having different `drawRect` implementation. In main controller, I initialize pattern child class based on selection using switch case.

```
ParentClass collView;

switch (selectedOptionIndex) {
            case 1:
                collView = [[ChildDesign alloc] initWithFrame:newframe];
                break;
            case 2:
                collView = [[ChildDesign2 alloc] initWithFrame:newframe]; //similar other classes
                break;
            case 3:
                collView = [[ChildDesign3 alloc] initWithFrame:newframe];
                break;
}
```

Problem is that I have got alot of options, say 50 - 100. Creating separate inherited classes (50 - 100 .h and .m files) would be really bad approach in my opinion and is bad programming practice.

So What pattern should I follow here to optimize my code? How should I create my child classes/ patterns? What will be best approach? An idea in my mind is to pass selected index to   I hope my Question is clear.. Thanks.

An idea in my mind is to create single child pattern class having selected index as a property. Based on selected index, I will implement `drawRect:` method. But there will be lot of if-else or switch cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to answer this, you must first understand at the level of `drawRect`.  Strictly speaking, if you genuinely have cause to differentiate classes according to `drawRect`, then having 50-100 child classes is what you should do.  However, it is a little hard to believe that *something* can't be salvaged between implementations.

For instance, say the only difference between these classes is the icon that gets drawn in the space indicated by `drawRect`.  At this point, it isn't `drawRect` that changes between one child class and another but the icon itself.  Therefore, in that case, you could simply create a property "icon" which, when `drawRect` is called, will draw that icon in the indicated space.

It is difficult to imagine a circumstance in which each child class would genuinely need to have its own implementation of `drawRect`, however I'm explicitly not discounting the possibility because it could be the case.  Suppose in one child class, you draw a triangle while in another you draw a circle, and in another still, you draw a rectangle.  If you cannot generalize this behavior, then you'd be correct to implement a child class for each one.  However, even if you could generalize by drawing an icon of a triangle or an icon of a circle, then that is already reason enough to have one class which does this for you.

More than likely in your circumstance, you could probably generalize it into a single parent class, or lacking that, no more than a handful of child classes for each option *type*.  Try to remember that when the code differs, you need a new class, but if the data differs, you only need a new instance.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for making things clear. My code differs for different patterns, so may be i should go with implementation of different classes. One more thing, I want to ask u if a lot of classes(files) will increase my app size drastically?

Comment: Try to find some common ground between implementations.  Just because you need 50-100 options doesn't necessarily mean you need 50-100 classes.  You need one for each *type* of implementation.  As for app size, app size will increase slightly, but most of the size increase comes from resource files such as images, not source.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're confusing classes with objects.  A class is a template, with the code included to implement the actual object, while an object is the actual value.  For instance you would create a Letter class, but wouldn't create a separate class for every letter of the alphabet.  You need to simplify `drawRect` enough so that it can be calculated from the smallest amount of data and code.  That data and code would go into your `ChildDesign`.